# Find set of points with maximum distance inside given intervals?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, intervals

Let $A$ be a set of $n$ closed intervals, $I_i$, with both extremes positive integers. Is there an efficient algorithm to find a set of $n$ points $P_i$, with $P_i \in I_i$, such that the minimum distance between all pairs of points is maximized?

Assume that the intervals are bounded by a positive integer $C$.

What's the complexity of this problem?

If the intervals are non-overlapping, I know how to solve this with linear programming (indeed, using a system of difference constraints and Bellman-Ford), but what can we say about the general case where intervals might overlap?

**Note:** Most comments/answers so far are looking for a polynomial solution. Note that it is possible that this problem is NP-complete. I know that it was  the style of this teacher to include problems for which students had to prove NP-completeness.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the subject?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have came back to this problem over a couple of months, but I haven't figured it out yet. No valuable ideas so far...

Comment: 1. You mention this was assigned on an exam.  What was the course?  What subjects were taught in the course?  In other words, what topics could people taking the exam have been expected to know?  Was it an undergraduate algorithms course?  A graduate course?  2. Are the points $P_1,\dots,P_n$ required to be integers, or can they be real numbers?

Comment: @D.W. The points can be real numbers, but if restricting $P_i$ to the integers makes a difference, I would like to know the solution in that case as well. The course was on algorithms and complexity. I attended it but did not do the exam myself since it did not give me credits. Topics covered included recurrence, greedy algorithms, some NP-complete problems (knapsack problem and finding Hamilton cycle come to mind), proving NP-completeness, etc.

Comment: I don't remember all the topics in the course, but I'm not taking the course anymore, so don't mind if you solve the problem using something you find on any book/paper! If you point me to the reference I'll read it.

Comment: Some special cases of your problem: 1. You can test in polynomial time whether there exists an integer solution where the minimum pairwise distance is $\ge 1$ (using bipartite matching / the Hungarian algorithm).  This lets you test whether the maximum attainable is $0$ or not.  But I don't know how to check in polytime whether there exists a set of $n$ points whose minimum pairwise distance is $\ge 2$. 2. If all intervals have length $\le 2$, you can check for an integer solution in polynomial time (via 2SAT).  But I don't know how to solve it in polytime if all intervals have length $\le 3$.